# Prolog program type error

Tags: prolog

This is one of the assignment questions which I'm currently working on (yes, this is homework):

```
moveSouth([_],_,_Num,_Moves,_Time).
moveSouth(Members,SouthGrp,Num,Moves,Time) :-
    member(X1/Y1,Members),
    member(X2/Y2,Members),
    X1 @< X2,
    (((NewTime is Time+Y1),(Y1>=Y2));((NewTime is Time+Y2),(Y1<Y2))),
    NewTime =< Num,
    subtract(Members,[X1/Y1,X2/Y2],NewFam),
    append(SouthGrp,[X1/Y1,X2/Y2],NewSouthGrp),
    append(Moves,[X1+X2],NewMoves),
    moveNorth(NewFam,NewSouthGrp,Num,NewMoves,NewTime).

 moveNorth(Member,SouthGrp,Num,Moves,Time) :-
    member(X1/Y1,SouthGrp),
    NewTime is Time+Y1,
    select(X1/Y1,SouthGrp,NewSouthGrp),
    moveSouth([X1/Y1|Member],Num,NewSouthGrp,[Moves|X1],NewTime).

 moveFamily(Name,Num,_Moves,_Time) :-
    family(Name,Members),
    moveSouth(Members,[],Num,[],0).
```

what I'm trying to do here is to move a List of names with property of Name/Time,
to the south side, each time i can only move 2 members to the South, then needs to
move one of the South members back to North.

now SWI-Prolog is giving me:

```
ERROR: =</2: Type error: `character' expected, found `mother/2'"
```

which I understand it means my types at `=<` operator is/are wrong. What I don't understand is what caused this to happen.

PS: The fact I used was:

```
family(original, [father/1, mother/2, child/5, granny/10]).
```

The query I used was:

```
moveFamily(original,19,Moves,Time).
```

Comment: Have you tried [tracing](http://www.csupomona.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/2_2.html) the program's execution?

Comment: @larsmans I actually had several problems and I fixed them, but this one I'm really troubled with, NewTime and Num aren't even characters.

Comment: If you want proper help, then please post the query that produces the error.

Comment: sorry forgot to, just posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1

The following line in your code assumes that `X1/Y1` and `X2/Y2` always occur next to each other (in that order) in the list of members:

```
subtract(Members, [X1/Y1,X2/Y2], NewFam),
```

But the way in which `X1/Y1` and `X2/Y2` are selected from the list of members shows that this need not be the case:

```
member(X1/Y1, Members),
member(X2/Y2, Members),
```

#### 2

Another bug is in `[Moves|X1]`, where `X1` need not be a list at all.

#### 3

Then the specific error that you asked your question about: in one call to `moveSouth/4` you have swapped the second and third argument which leads to `INTEGER =< LIST`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: it's now giving me false answers, but I guess I'll try to figure it out myself, thanks for the help.

Comment: @user3514453 Your third mistake was indeed probably a typo, but the first and second point to fundamental aspects of lists (order does matter as opposed to sets) and Prolog list construction using the `[HEAD|TAIL]` notation, in which `TAIL` must itself be a list.